# HTML5 video on e-mail clients

Tags: html, css, email, html5-video, html-email

first time posting here!

I have a hard time to get the e-mail clients to render videos in html5. I tried some things and found a few that help but don't solve the problem. Here is some information that already googled and have tested:

• The tested email clients are !Yahoo, Gmail, Hotmail and Outlook. All clients that i tested don't rendered the videos.
• In my research  i found some contradictions articles where some places say hotmail began to render html5 videos but others are saying that only display a fallback image. On my tests, only fallback images or posters shows up. =(

Here is the code that i used in my tests (the best i already founded so far...):

```
.ExternalClass td.video_holder {display:none !important;}
.ExternalClass div.android {display:block !important;width:100% !important;height:200px !important;}

                    <div align="center" class="video_holder">                            
                    <video width="320" height="176" controls>
                        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
                          <a href="#" ><img height="176" src="http://www.emailonacid.com/images/blog_images/Emailology/2013/html5_video/backup_bunny2.jpg" width="320" alt="Just a video" /></a>
                    </video>
                    </div>
                    <div class="android" style="display:none; width:0px; height:0px; overflow:hidden;">
                      <p>Android Div</p>
                      <a href="#" ><img height="176" 
                        src="http://www.emailonacid.com/images/blog_images/Emailology/2013/html5_video/backup_bunny2.jpg" width="320" alt="Just a video" /></a>
                    </div>
```

Another code I tested was the litmus email with the video running in the background and here we have a user opening the email:

https://litmus.com/builder/a908938

http://www.mobypicture.com/user/asouers/view/16785201

Now  guys, what i'm doing wrong here? Nothing? Everything?

And another thing: I'm not a expert level on HTML5 and CSS3 and don't know another programming language, so take easy with me! Rs.

Comment: Generally no. The common denominator for mail client acceptance of HTML is very low. your safest bet would be to put in a static image that you've photoshopped a play button onto and use it as a link to the actual video. I don't know about you, but I would NOT want to be spammed with a video in my inbox.

Comment: Well, depending on how the video is displayed (as the example I gave of litmus) may be acceptable to a video in your inbox. But of course that goes from person to person! But really, I have to work around this problem with a static image.

But thanks for answering my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 video is [very poorly supported in email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). Even iOS Mail, considered to be one of the *good* email clients for rendering code, [removed video support in iOS 9](https://litmus.com/blog/what-email-designers-need-to-know-about-ios-9). I don't know if there's anything wrong with your code, but unfortunately I don't think it matters.

Comment: Well...Damn! kkkk

I'll have to do something to avoid this problem. But anyway, thank you for answering my question!